# When asking to launch my application to google assistant I get a message about google sharing data preventing to launch the app

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm trying to deploy my first Dialogflow / actions-on-google App (Pamela Target). I could test it easily until a few weeks but recently I started to get a message with : (translated from french: Service and confidentiality) saying that informations are shared with third the third party app  with an 'OK' button to click. 
see : [screenshot](https://photos.app.goo.gl/yKTw33NHg9v1fsQA8)
.But when I click: everything is blank... it stops, even not starting the app...

I tried on the Google simulator, and it works fine
I tried on the Google home mini, and it works fine
only on my android device it does this...

I am still hoping to find either what parameter/configuration or what i may have done in the code that could prevent the app to work on the phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of unsuccessful tries, It happened that there seemed to be an issue on the testing device; I had to reinstall all google apps, this allowed me to have a working "ok" button. Probably a software compatibility issue within google apps.